# How to use Oracle Dblinks that honor referential integrity constraints?

Tags: oracle, foreign-key-relationship, dblink

I have a need to move data between two identical Oracle databases. I have figured out how to use dbLinks to achieve most of it. Here is my confusion.

Lets say I have Table A, which refers to Table B present in DB1 and also similar structure in DB2. Is there any way possible for me to create db link to move data between Table A in DB1 and DB2 which automatically copies the relevant data in Table B to support referential constraints (without me having to spell it out)?

Thanks
Kay

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to duplicate the foreign key and check constraints in DB2.TableB in the destination table DB1.TableA.

A little more work is to create a materialized view in DB1 along the lines of

`Create Materialized View TableA as Select * from TableB@DB2.link;`

Refresh as required...  You cannot do a fast refresh on a remote database but very few applications require true real time synchronization.

Comment: I know this is old, but for anyone else who found this answer via google like I did, you certainly can do a fast refresh over a dblink: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122299/oracle-materialized-view-overloads-database/122303#122303

Comment: @KrisJohnston can you add a "works on Oracle versions xxxx" to your answer in the link?

Comment: Done, but i'm not sure how relevant that really is since that has worked in all major Oracle Releases starting in 10g (that I've personally tested).  If you actually have a 9i or earlier version, it is way past due for an upgrade...